# How can I access the XSD from URN given below?

Tags: xml, xsd

> Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04" >xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
>
> .. and so on..

Comment: What kind of input is given? This does not look like valid XML

Answer (score 3):

A namespace is just a unique identifier, it doesn't tell you the location of a schema. This is always true, but it's especially true when the namespace is a URN, which is deliberately designed to hold no location information.

So the only way to find a schema for that namespace is to search for it on the web, or in your local public library, or wherever you normally look for such things.

Comment: This prevented me raising a similar question and should be accepted as the answer. I think the question is not so bad in terms that it managed to catch my case too and help me learn more by myself!

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be from ISO 20022 (payment and interbanking messages standard). You may have luck finding a schema on https://www.iso20022.org/,
though be aware that ISO 20022 schemas are frequently customized for a given vertical market.